# Docstring tag for 'yield' keyword

Tags: python, documentation, docstring

There are some tags for docstrings in python, like `@param` and `@return`, for example:

```
def my_method(a_param):
    ''' @param a_param: Description of this param
        @return: The return value of the method
    '''
    return int(a_param) * (other or 1)
```

What can I use for documenting generators? specially the `yield` keyword, like:

```
def my_generator(from=0):
    ''' @param from: The initial value
        @yield: A lot of values
    '''
    yield a_value
```

I understand that `@return an iterator` can be used here, but I don't know if it's correct because a generator can return values also.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, those tags are used by third-party tools, and not anything in python itself.

Comment: A generator can `yield` values, it `return`s a generator object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would consider `@return` to be appropriate in this case because the function actually returns an iterator object with a `next` or `send` method.  The validity of the statement `x = my_generator(from=3)` implies that `my_generator` really does return something.  It merely does so without using the `return` statement to do it.

In some ways, functions containing a `yield` statement or expression behave like classes, because they are factories that return objects with predictable properties.  However, because generator functions can themselves be declared and invoked as instance methods, I do not think of them as classes.