# Is there a Sphinx reST Python docstring field for yields?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm trying to use reST-style docstrings, i.e.

```py
def foo(bar):
    """a method that takes a bar

    :param bar: a Bar instance
    :type bar: Bar
```

Is there a standard way to document `yields`? I looked at http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists, a-la this question [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334531/python-documentation-standard-for-docstring ], but no luck. I'm imagining something like,

```
:yields: transformed bars
:yield type: Baz
```

Comment: Close to [Docstring tag for 'yield' keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652540/docstring-tag-for-yield-keyword?rq=1).

Comment: I don't know reST, but my guess would be that you document it the way you'd document any other "returns an iterator" function. The use of `yield` is an implementation detail.

Comment: yeah, I know the other question is similar, I want a reST-specific answer, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

**Python 3.5 `Iterator[]` annotation**

They offer a standardized `Iterator[]` syntax for this as documented at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator

Before Python 3, I recommend that you use this syntax to make it easier to port later on:

```
from typing import List
def f():
    """
    :rtype: Iterator[:class:`SomeClass`]
    """
    yield SomeClass()
```

And after Python 3, use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx-autodoc-annotation with syntax:

```
from typing import Iterator
def f() -> Iterator[SomeClass]:
    yield SomeClass()
```

Answer (score 5):

I have reviewed the other answer and it doesn't in my opinion answer the question.

The way to document a generator, although not the best, is by using `:return` as in the rest of the docs. Use the description to give notice that it is a generator.

Yields from Google/Numpy style docs convert yields to return clauses.

https://bitbucket.org/RobRuana/sphinx-contrib/src/a06ae33f1c70322c271a97133169d96a5ce1a6c2/napoleon/sphinxcontrib/napoleon/docstring.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#docstring.py-678:680